# MongoDB findOne() returns value in the function but doesn't return the value in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So I'm trying to assign values from MongoDB in node with a function. My problem is, it finds the data but it returns undefined outside of the findOne function.

Code:

```
async function findFile(userid) {

    let ufile = mCollection.findOne({"uid": userid}, function(err, res) {
        console.log(res);
        return res;
    });

    console.log(ufile);

};

findFile(authId);
```

Results:
[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ6FZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning inside the callback. This means that mCollection.findOne itself doesn't return any value.

What you can do instead is log the value inside the callback like so:

```
async function findFile(userid) {

    let ufile = mCollection.findOne({"uid": userid}, function(err, res) {

        console.log(ufile);

    });


};

findFile(authId);
```

Or run the function as a promise, and await it:

```
async function findFile(userid) {

    let ufile = await mCollection.findOne({"uid": userid});
    console.log(ufile)

};

findFile(authId);
```